Advice on how to script out existing Azure (logical) SQL Server logins and mapped database users (with permissions/group memberships)
Context: We have an Azure (logical) SQL server with a number of logins. Each login has been assigned specific permissions and is mapped as a user for databases hosted on the Azure (logical) SQL server.
What I am aiming to do is script out each of the logins and their mapped database users, along with assigned permissions at server and database level.
Previously when managing SQL Server hosted on VM's, I was able to do this with the 'sp_Help_RevLogin' procedure, which worked perfectly...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances
However, this seemingly does not work for Azure (logical) SQL servers/Azure databases.
I've also looked in to the DBA-Tools cmdlet DBA-CopyLogin
https://docs.dbatools.io/Copy-DbaLogin.html
Which seems to do what I need, but I'm encountering some issues with testing due to our Azure Entra ID muti factor authentication policy.
Does any one know of a method that can achieve the same outcome that sp_Help_RevLogin has for SQL Server instances on VM's??
